# jQuery close button for toggleClass and slideToggle not working as expected

Tags: jquery, removeclass, toggleclass

I have a simple slide toggle setup that I want to add a close button to, but it seems that removeClass() isn't working.

When clicking the close link, I want to return to the previous color (remove .active) and  leave open any others that are open. In other words, this close link should only affect the toggle that it's in. I thought it would be a simple matter of removing the "active" class from the title div and the content div and slide up the content div.

The slideUp part works fine, but the "active" class doesn't toggle off or remove.

Here's my js:

```
$("h2.titleTrigger").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
return false;
});

//CLOSE LINK
$(".closeIt").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest(".toggleContent").slideUp("fast");
$(this).closest(".toggleContent").removeClass("active");
$(this).closest("h2.titleTrigger").removeClass("active");
 });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NVjK4/)

I've also tried toggleClass instead of removeClass, but that doesn't work either. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h2` is not inside the `.toggleContent`, nor is it associated with the close button, so try this instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/NVjK4/1/))

```
$(".closeIt").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".toggleContent")
        .slideUp("fast")
        .removeClass("active")
        .prev("h2.titleTrigger").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I was thinking (.prev()) but couldn't seem to find the answer. Thanks a million!! And also thanks for the brief explanation... that's really helpful to n00bs like me :)

Answer (score 1):

to answer your request:
"When closing, I want to leave open any others that are open. In other words, this close link should only close the toggle that it's in."

this fiddle should do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/TpQff/1/

jquery:

```
$("h2.titleTrigger").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
    $("#mydiv").slideToggle("fast");


return false;
});

//CLOSE LINK
$(".closeIt").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().slideUp("fast");
    $(this).closest(".toggleContent").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("h2.titleTrigger").removeClass("active");
 });
```

html

```
<h2 class="titleTrigger">slide it</h2>

<div id="mydiv">
    <h2 class="closeIt">close  it</h2>
    inside div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question. I'm wondering how to use a "close" link to get a div that's been toggled open and had classes added to it to toggle close and remove those classes.

Comment: here's a working fiddle for your updated and clarified question:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/huuML/1/

Answer (score 1):

you're not selecting the element; closest() will never find the h2.

Try this instead:

```
$(this).closest(".toggleContent").prev().removeClass("active");
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gw63h/